# Grafana-Kubernetes Integration

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I am having the following questions:

Actually, I am using grafana open source service in Azure Virtual Machine. I would like to see the Kubernetes SLA Metrics on Grafana. When I had googled for it, then I had got the following page: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/kubernetes/

When I tried to follow the tutorial, I am not able to find the onboarding or lightning icon. Is this integration only for grafana enterprise? If no, please let me know, how to proceed further.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Regards,
Chaitanya

Comment: if you are using some comercial products(azure...), you would expect some documents provided by the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an Azure Managed Grafana service on Azure. When create an instance you can grant it access to Azure Monitor which will serve up statistics from your AKS clusters.